# C# Pass Class as parameter to method and call static method in there

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to C# and looking the best way to do the following implementation.

My project got several Model classes (like 25) and each class got a static method called "process()", which just takes a bit of time to finish it's task.

I need to call all these method in each class one after another and to add some logs (write status of method execution in to file) to track execution.

I can simply do the following, But surely there should be a better professional way to do this

```
Log.WriteLog(DateTime.Now + " Class A Process Started");
ClassA.Process()
Log.WriteLog(DateTime.Now + " Class A Process Finished");
Log.WriteLog(DateTime.Now + " Class B Process Started");
ClassB.Process()
Log.WriteLog(DateTime.Now + " Class B Process Finished");
............ continue 25 classes
```

What I am trying to do is to write a method and just Add Logs and repetitive work in there..

```
private void CommonMethod(Class)
{
   Check what class
   Add Process started Log
   Call Process method
   Add proicess finished Log
}
```

Comment: you need aspect oriented programming or stragegy do each of the models implement the same interface and signature for `Process`? can you put them in an array or other collection?

Comment: This is the *type*. You want to pass the *type* and call one of its static methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create function that takes a delegate and performs the logging, something like this:

```
public void ProcessAndLog(Action action, String processName)
{
  Log.WriteLog(DateTime.Now + $" Class {processName} Process Started");
  action();
  Log.WriteLog(DateTime.Now + $" Class {processName} Process Finished");
}
```

and call it like so:

```
ProcessAndLog(ClassA.Process, "A"); //"A" could be part of ClassA - e.g. ClassA.Name;
ProcessAndLog(ClassB.Process, "B");
//etc
```

This will work so long as every `Process` method has no params and retuns void - the signature of the `Action` delegate.

If it has parameters, you can call it like so:

```
ProcessAndLog(() => ClassC.Process("value"), "C");
```

If you need a return value, consider a `Func<T>` instead of `Action`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
private void CommonMethod<T>()
{
    //Add Process started Log
    //Call Process method
    typeof(T).GetMethod("process")?.Invoke(null, null); // not target needed
    //Add proicess finished Log
}
```

**Usage:**

```
CommonMethod<ClassA>();
CommonMethod<ClassB>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Static interfaces don't exist in C#. The only way to reference a static member of a class is by its class name and member name.

An alternative would be to use reflection. Get the static method by it's string name and invoke it. Like this:

```
static void CommonMethod(Type type)
{
    MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("TheStaticMethodName");

    if (methodInfo != null)
    {
        methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[0]);
    }
}

//Invoke it like this
CommonMethod(typeof(MyStaticType));
```

The first parameter for `Invoke` is the target. For an instance method you would pass a class instance you want to invoke on, but for static members just put `null`.

The second parameter is the arguments. You can put an empty array the if there's no arguments.

Also, you could have the same method with a generic type like this:

```
static void CommonMethod<T>()
{
    MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(T).GetMethod("TheStaticMethodName");

    if (methodInfo != null)
    {
        methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[0]);
    }
}
```

Note that generics aren't always the best since they generate a lot of stuff at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another suggestion:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new Calculate { a = 1, b = 2 };
        var y = new Calculate { a = 10, b = 20 };
        var z = new Calculate { a = 100, b = 200 };

        var calculations = new List<Calculate>{
            new Calculate() { a = 1, b = 2 },
            new Calculate() { a = 10, b = 20 },
            new Calculate() { a = 100, b = 200 }
        };

        calculations.ForEach(c =>
        {
            c.Process();
        });
    }
}

class Calculate
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }

    public void Process()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a + b);
    }
}
```